# Создать общие тестовые данные для всех тестов. без @Before-метода

Tags: junit

Есть несколько дочерних тестовых классов, которые при запуске используют @Before метод родительского класса. Как можно избавиться от @Before метода? Пробовала через @BeforeClass, но он статический, а в классе много @Autowaierd полей. Бины не подтягиваются.

Comment: Чем не годится `@Before` метод, почему от него хотите избавиться?

Comment: Тесты работают медленно.

Comment: Во-первых, вы точно знаете , что причина в `@Before`? А во-вторых, что мешает методу `@Before` проверить, не создано ли уже все то, что он пробует создать и не создавать. Таким образом тестовые данные будут созданы один раз - перед первым тестом. Это самый практичный способ. Альтернативный способ, это создание тестовых данных при создании тестового контекста и пользоваться тем, что тестовая инфраструктура спринг кеширует контексты, если properties и список конфигурационных файлов/классов такой же.

Comment: Я только начала работать и с тестами только знакомлюсь. Про зависимость скорости от @Before сказал лид. Он же и проучил разобраться. Большое спасибо за советы. Сейчас попробую)